# Python PPTX Internal Hyperlinks workaround function

Tags: python, python-pptx

I tried to follow example as discussed in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-pptx/nrUkiQQHyZo , however ended up with an error `'Slide' object has no attribute 'rels'`.

The minimal code I'm experimenting tries to build a hyperlink in first slide to third slide.

```
import pptx
import pptx.enum
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.action import PP_ACTION
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

#very minimal Powerpoint template
prs = Presentation("tpl.pptx")

# create 3 slides, each with single text placeholder
s1 = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])
s2 = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])
s3 = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])

# create internal hyperlink
rId = s1.part.relate_to(s3, RT.SLIDE)
r = s1.placeholders[10].text_frame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
r.text = "Link to Slide 3"
rPr = r._r.get_or_add_rPr()

hlinkClick = rPr.add_hlinkClick(rId)
hlinkClick.set('action', 'ppaction://hlinksldjump')

# ERROR WHEN SAVING - Slide' object has no attribute 'rels #
prs.save("Test.pptx")
```

How to resolve the error? Or perhaps, is there a simpler way to achieve this?

EDIT: Full Stack Trace

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-60361164c736> in <module>()
     23 
     24 # ERROR WHEN SAVING - Slide' object has no attribute 'rels #
---> 25 prs.save("Test.pptx")

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\presentation.py in save(self, file)
     44         to a file (a string) or a file-like object.
     45         """
---> 46         self.part.save(file)
     47 
     48     @property

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\parts\presentation.py in save(self, path_or_stream)
    116         object.
    117         """
--> 118         self.package.save(path_or_stream)
    119 
    120     def slide_id(self, slide_part):

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in save(self, pkg_file)
    162         a file (a string) or a file-like object.
    163         """
--> 164         for part in self.parts:
    165             part.before_marshal()
    166         PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts)

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in parts(self)
    139         package.
    140         """
--> 141         return [part for part in self.iter_parts()]
    142 
    143     def relate_to(self, part, reltype):

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    139         package.
    140         """
--> 141         return [part for part in self.iter_parts()]
    142 
    143     def relate_to(self, part, reltype):

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in iter_parts(self)
     54                     yield part
     55 
---> 56         for part in walk_parts(self):
     57             yield part
     58 

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in walk_parts(source, visited)
     51                 yield part
     52                 new_source = part
---> 53                 for part in walk_parts(new_source, visited):
     54                     yield part
     55 

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in walk_parts(source, visited)
     51                 yield part
     52                 new_source = part
---> 53                 for part in walk_parts(new_source, visited):
     54                     yield part
     55 

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in walk_parts(source, visited)
     51                 yield part
     52                 new_source = part
---> 53                 for part in walk_parts(new_source, visited):
     54                     yield part
     55 

C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in walk_parts(source, visited)
     42         """
     43         def walk_parts(source, visited=list()):
---> 44             for rel in source.rels.values():
     45                 if rel.is_external:
     46                     continue

AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'rels'
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Usually this means a slide is used as the slide part; those two were separated in the code a while back. I'd try changing `s3` to `s3.part` in the line that starts with `rId =` and see if that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment by @scanny, changing s3 to s3.part works well.

```
# create internal hyperlink
rId = s1.part.relate_to(s3.part, RT.SLIDE)
r = s1.placeholders[10].text_frame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
r.text = "Link to Slide 3"
rPr = r._r.get_or_add_rPr()
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting together all the information already posted in this thread, here is a minimal example:

```
# Workaround for python-pptx lack of internal hyperlink support
from pptx.enum.action import PP_ACTION
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT
def Hyperlink( run_object, source_slide, destination_slide ):
    rId = source_slide.part.relate_to(destination_slide.part, RT.SLIDE)
    rPr = run_object._r.get_or_add_rPr()
    hlinkClick = rPr.add_hlinkClick(rId)
    hlinkClick.set('action', 'ppaction://hlinksldjump')

# Example of usage:

from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
slide = dict()

# Make Slides

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide['title'] = prs.slides.add_slide( title_slide_layout )
title = slide['title'].shapes.title
title.text = 'Presentation with Internal Hyperlinks'

two_content_slide = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide['table of contents'] = prs.slides.add_slide( two_content_slide )
shapes = slide['table of contents'].shapes
title = shapes.title
title.text = 'Table of contents'

two_content_slide = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide['slide a'] = prs.slides.add_slide( two_content_slide )
shapes = slide['slide a'].shapes
title = shapes.title
title.text = 'Slide A'

two_content_slide = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide['slide b'] = prs.slides.add_slide( two_content_slide )
shapes = slide['slide b'].shapes
title = shapes.title
title.text = 'Slide B'

# Populate contents (with hyperlinks)

shapes = slide['table of contents'].shapes
body = shapes.placeholders[1]
tf = body.text_frame
p = tf.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.text = 'Slide A'
Hyperlink( r, slide['table of contents'], slide['slide a'] )
p = tf.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.text = 'Slide B'
Hyperlink( r, slide['table of contents'], slide['slide b'] )

# Save as .pptx file

prs.save( 'hyperlink_slides.pptx' )
```

Hope this helps!