# Python PPTX Internal Hyperlink

Tags: python-pptx

I'm trying to use python-pptx to use a click action on a shape to go to another slide in the presentation.

Similar to this question:
[Python PPTX Internal Hyperlinks workaround function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704555/python-pptx-internal-hyperlinks-workaround-function)

Unlike the other tutorials and guides I have seen, I am not looking to add a text run to my shape, my desired behavior is that clicking anywhere on the shape (which has no text) will result in the action behavior. Attempts to follow the guides and documentation have been unsuccessful. I'm able to grab the rId, but not able to add the attribute to the object to enable the linking.

```
rId = s1.part.relate_to(s3.part, RT.SLIDE)
#We want to make the entire shape have the linking behavior here
r = s1.placeholders[10].text_frame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
r.text = "Link to Slide 3"
rPr = r._r.get_or_add_rPr()

hlinkClick = rPr.add_hlinkClick(rId)
hlinkClick.set('action', 'ppaction://hlinksldjump')
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code should suffice:

```py
shape.click_action.target_slide = destination
```

Here's a small working example.

```py
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE

prs = Presentation()
layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
source = prs.slides.add_slide(layout)
destination = prs.slides.add_slide(layout)

width = height = Inches(1.0)
shape = source.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, 0, 0, width, height)

# the linking part
shape.click_action.target_slide = destination

prs.save('linked_slide.pptx')
```

The [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-hyperlink.html) also states some possible relative linking action (link to previous, next, first or last slide), but I didn't get this to work yet.