# Creating python PPTX Internal Hyperlinks prior to creating slides

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

On the topic of [Python PPTX Internal Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772000/python-pptx-internal-hyperlink)

Is there a way to create Hyperlinks prior to creating the slides that they will be linked to?

E.g. create a table of contents slide with hyperlinks to the slides that will be added later, the number of slides wont always be the same as it will be edited by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. Here's what I found working with a currently selected shape on a slide. I expect you'd be applying hyperlinks to a textrange instead, but the general idea's the same.

A hyperlink to another slide contains no .Address and the .SubAddress looks like:

```
SlideID,SlideIndex,SlideTitle
```

SlideTitle can be blank, so I tested with this to link to a third slide that wasn't there:

```
Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.subaddress = ",3,"
```

No errors, but the link doesn't work either.

This DOES work, however:

```
Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.subaddress = "258,3,"
```

I run this on a selected shape on the first slide then later add a third slide and the link jumps to it.

The trick then becomes: How will you know what the SlideID will be, this slide you haven't yet added?  In a new presentation, PPT will give the first slide an ID of 256 and increment the ID for each new slide you add, but it'll be quite tricky to keep track of SlideIDs and SlideIndexes if you're adding new slides at random places in a presentation, that may have had slides added and deleted beforehand.

Personally, I think I'd add blank slides ahead of time, link to them, then add whatever content's necessary.

Comment: This should work perfectly for me as I will be adding slides from a predetermined list in a database so a simple counter should be fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Certainly the straightforward way won't work, but it's hard to say never against human ingenuity.

Anyway, the way this mechanism works is based on the PowerPoint hyperlink behavior, there are just special "action" verbs that mean "jump internally" rather than "jump to web address". The verb in this case would be `NAMED_SLIDE` (although `NEXT_SLIDE`, `LAST_SLIDE`, etc. are also available). The "name" of the slide in the XML is its relationship id, basically a keyword like `"rId7"` for the mapping of one PPTX package part (e.g. slide) to another.

Since there isn't a slide yet, there can be no relationship. Having such a "dangling" relationship would very likely trigger a repair error, but I can't see it working out in any case. Creating a new slide will create a new relationship without regard to relationships that are already there, so best case is your "pre-creation" relationship just gets ignored.

I think you're going to need a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks scanny
That was initial thought but wasn't sure, I might need to do some reordering

Comment: @NerdDegreeBurn Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't neglect to accept an answer that answers your question. This is how you say "Thanks!" to a respondent for taking the time to answer, and it also builds your reputation points. You accept by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.